# Getting JSON data from a URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I'm trying to read JSON data from a webserver but am lost. I don't get any errors but my code doesn't display anything either. Here's the sample

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON('http://api.example.com/madata.php?zip=08854&key=36e25aa7518a6092&callback=?', function(json) {                                   //this works. but doesn't display any alerts or data
               //$.getJSON('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo&callback=?', function(json) {   //this works. notice the callback
               //$.getJSON('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo', function(json) {              //this also works
                    alert("good");
                    alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
               });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'placeholder'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you notice I've tried 3 $.getJSON statements with different URLs, 2 work, but the one with the key in the url doesn't display any alert upon success.

The "example" url "http://api.example.com/madata.php?zip=08854&key=36e25aa7518a6092&callback=?"  works fine (when example replaced with an actual domain) if posted in the browser, and returns JSON data as

```
[{"FCCID":"52601","Calls":"WAWZ","StnFreq":"99.1","MktID":"18","StnOwner":"Pillar of Fire","StnNameHD1":"Star 99.1","StnDescrHD1":"Great Christian Music!","StnContentHD1":"Music","StnGenreHD1":"Religious","StnAltGenreHD1":null,"StnLangHD1":"English","StnWebsiteHD1":"www.star991fm.com","StnFBHD1":"facebook.com\/star991fm","StnTwitterHD1":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/star991fm","StnEmailHD1":"","StnSMSHD1":"","StnPhoneHD1":"(800) 791-0991","StnRebrHD1":"none","StnFeatHD1":"0","StnAEHD1":"Unknown","StnLogoHD1":"http:\/\/apistatic.ibiquity.com\/uploads\/logos\/5\/e\/5e0838767af7ede3d99de2c093be5c2b.png","StnAudioHD1":"","StnNameHD2":"WAWZ-HD2","StnDescrHD2":"Teaching and Preaching","StnContentHD2":"News\/Talk","StnGenreHD2":"Religious","StnAltGenreHD2":null,"StnLangHD2":"English","StnWebsiteHD2":"www.star991fm.com","StnFBHD2":"","StnTwitterHD2":"","StnEmailHD2":"","StnSMSHD2":"","StnPhoneHD2":"(800) 791-0991","StnRebrHD2":"none","StnFeatHD2":"0","StnAEHD2":"Unknown","StnLogoHD2":"http:\/\/apistatic.ibiquity.com\/uploads\/logos\/5\/e\/5e0838767af7ede3d99de2c093be5c2b.png","StnAudioHD2":"","StnNameHD3":"WAWZ-HD3","StnDescrHD3":"The Energy","StnContentHD3":"Music","StnGenreHD3":"Religious","StnAltGenreHD3":null,"StnLangHD3":"English","StnWebsiteHD3":"www.star991fm.com","StnFBHD3":"","StnTwitterHD3":"","StnEmailHD3":"","StnSMSHD3":"","StnPhoneHD3":"(800) 791-0991","StnRebrHD3":"none","StnFeatHD3":"0","StnAEHD3":"Unknown","StnLogoHD3":"http:\/\/apistatic.ibiquity.com\/uploads\/logos\/5\/e\/5e0838767af7ede3d99de2c093be5c2b.png","StnAudioHD3":"","StnNameHD4":"","StnDescrHD4":"","StnContentHD4":"","StnGenreHD4":null,"StnAltGenreHD4":null,"StnLangHD4":null,"StnWebsiteHD4":"","StnFBHD4":"","StnTwitterHD4":"","StnEmailHD4":"","StnSMSHD4":"","StnPhoneHD4":"","StnRebrHD4":"none","StnFeatHD4":"0","StnAEHD4":"Unknown","StnLogoHD4":"","StnAudioHD4":""},{"FCCID":"49587","Calls":"WDHA","StnFreq":"105.5","MktID":"20","StnOwner":"Greater Media","StnNameHD1":"","StnDescrHD1":"The Rock of New Jersey","StnContentHD1":"Music","StnGenreHD1":"Rock","StnAltGenreHD1":null,"StnLangHD1":null,"StnWebsiteHD1":"www.wdha.com","StnFBHD1":"www.facebook.com\/pages\/1055-WDHA","StnTwitterHD1":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/wdhafm","StnEmailHD1":"","StnSMSHD1":"","StnPhoneHD1":"(973) 455-1055","StnRebrHD1":"","StnFeatHD1":"0","StnAEHD1":"Live","StnLogoHD1":"http:\/\/apistatic.ibiquity.com\/uploads\/logos\/e\/b\/eb72e37fe8f446bd44d783b1b641fff0.png","StnAudioHD1":"","StnNameHD2":"","StnDescrHD2":"","StnContentHD2":"","StnGenreHD2":null,"StnAltGenreHD2":null,"StnLangHD2":null,"StnWebsiteHD2":"","StnFBHD2":"","StnTwitterHD2":"","StnEmailHD2":"","StnSMSHD2":"","StnPhoneHD2":"","StnRebrHD2":"","StnFeatHD2":"0","StnAEHD2":"Unknown","StnLogoHD2":"","StnAudioHD2":"","StnNameHD3":"","StnDescrHD3":"","StnContentHD3":"","StnGenreHD3":null,"StnAltGenreHD3":null,"StnLangHD3":null,"StnWebsiteHD3":"","StnFBHD3":"","StnTwitterHD3":"","StnEmailHD3":"","StnSMSHD3":"","StnPhoneHD3":"","StnRebrHD3":"","StnFeatHD3":"0","StnAEHD3":"Unknown","StnLogoHD3":"","StnAudioHD3":"","StnNameHD4":"","StnDescrHD4":"","StnContentHD4":"","StnGenreHD4":null,"StnAltGenreHD4":null,"StnLangHD4":null,"StnWebsiteHD4":"","StnFBHD4":"","StnTwitterHD4":"","StnEmailHD4":"","StnSMSHD4":"","StnPhoneHD4":"","StnRebrHD4":"","StnFeatHD4":"0","StnAEHD4":"Unknown","StnLogoHD4":"","StnAudioHD4":""}]
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something stupid here. I'm completely new to Javascript and just starting to learn.

Comment: If your code is not running on api.example.com, then you're probably tripping over CORS issues - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

Comment: @AdrianWragg yes, it's not running on api.example.com, that's why I'm making the request using JSONP. At least I think I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get( "http://api.example.com/madata.php?zip=08854&key=36e25aa7518a6092&callback=?", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.FCCID);
}, "json" );
```

This should help you. You can do what you want with the returned data.

Comment: Thanks, but that does the same thing as before.

Comment: Look at your console log and paste what is the error. Can you give me the url of the api to try with it?

Comment: that server doesn't support JSONP or CORS, so you'll need a server proxy to use the API from JS.

Comment: @dandavis That's correct. I confirmed that it doesn't support JSONP. I'll have to now find another way to get the data. Thanks.